# Android Visualizer Detect Beat? And Visualizer.setCaptureSize() not Working? Alternatives?

Tags: android, audio, visualizer

I am using The Visualizer to draw a Visualization of a Sound File that I am Playing. The sound wave is displaying, however I would like to make it less detailed, as it has an effect on my frame-rate. There is very limited documentation for this. So I have attempted to do the following:

```
mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(2);
```

To set the capture rate to a very low value. However, it appears that the line is being drawn with the same amount of detail. I have read in the documentation that:

```
Sets the capture size, i.e. the number of bytes returned by getWaveForm(byte[]) and getFft(byte[]) methods.
```

Another issue that I have, is that I would like to detect sounds with a high energy level in the sound File that I am playing so I can visually represent them on the screen. For example: The screen flashes along with the baseline. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void setupVisualizer() {
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mpSong.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(
            new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
                public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                        byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                    Game.updateVisualizer(bytes);
                }

                public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                        byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                }
            }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
}
```

Is it possible to detect certain sounds inside this listener? Or what are the alternatives? 
Sorry for my bad english. Thank you very much for your time friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok after several Hours of Testing and Researching I have found a solution. It may not be very accurate, but it is the only alternative I could come up with. I made a class called BeatDetector:

```
public class BeatDetectorByFrequency {
private static final String TAG = "TEST";

private Visualizer mVisualizer = null;

private double mRunningSoundAvg[];
private double mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[];
private int mNumberOfSamplesInOneSec;
private long mSystemTimeStartSec;
// FREQS
private static final int LOW_FREQUENCY = 300;
private static final int MID_FREQUENCY = 2500;
private static final int HIGH_FREQUENCY = 10000;
private OnBeatDetectedListener onBeatDetectedListener = null;

public BeatDetectorByFrequency() {
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mRunningSoundAvg = new double[3];
    mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec = new double[3];
    mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[0] = -1;
    mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[1] = -1;
    mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[2] = -1;
}

public void link(MediaPlayer player) {
    if (player == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot link to null MediaPlayer");
    }
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(player.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);

    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
            // DO NOTHING
        }

        @Override
        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate) {
            updateVisualizerFFT(bytes);
        }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
            Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, false, true);
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    mSystemTimeStartSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void release() {
    if (mVisualizer != null) {
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
        mVisualizer.release();
    }
}

public void pause() {
    if (mVisualizer != null) {
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public void resume() {
    if (mVisualizer != null) {
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

public void updateVisualizerFFT(byte[] audioBytes) {
    int energySum = 0;
    energySum += Math.abs(audioBytes[0]);
    int k = 2;
    double captureSize = mVisualizer.getCaptureSize() / 2;
    int sampleRate = mVisualizer.getSamplingRate() / 2000;
    double nextFrequency = ((k / 2) * sampleRate) / (captureSize);
    while (nextFrequency < LOW_FREQUENCY) {
        energySum += Math.sqrt((audioBytes[k] * audioBytes[k])
                * (audioBytes[k + 1] * audioBytes[k + 1]));
        k += 2;
        nextFrequency = ((k / 2) * sampleRate) / (captureSize);
    }
    double sampleAvgAudioEnergy = (double) energySum
            / (double) ((k * 1.0) / 2.0);

    mRunningSoundAvg[0] += sampleAvgAudioEnergy;
    if ((sampleAvgAudioEnergy > mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[0])
            && (mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[0] > 0)) {
        fireBeatDetectedLowEvent(sampleAvgAudioEnergy);
    }
    energySum = 0;
    while (nextFrequency < MID_FREQUENCY) {
        energySum += Math.sqrt((audioBytes[k] * audioBytes[k])
                * (audioBytes[k + 1] * audioBytes[k + 1]));
        k += 2;
        nextFrequency = ((k / 2) * sampleRate) / (captureSize);
    }

    sampleAvgAudioEnergy = (double) energySum / (double) ((k * 1.0) / 2.0);
    mRunningSoundAvg[1] += sampleAvgAudioEnergy;
    if ((sampleAvgAudioEnergy > mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[1])
            && (mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[1] > 0)) {
        fireBeatDetectedMidEvent(sampleAvgAudioEnergy);
    }
    energySum = Math.abs(audioBytes[1]);

    while ((nextFrequency < HIGH_FREQUENCY) && (k < audioBytes.length)) {
        energySum += Math.sqrt((audioBytes[k] * audioBytes[k])
                * (audioBytes[k + 1] * audioBytes[k + 1]));
        k += 2;
        nextFrequency = ((k / 2) * sampleRate) / (captureSize);
    }

    sampleAvgAudioEnergy = (double) energySum / (double) ((k * 1.0) / 2.0);
    mRunningSoundAvg[2] += sampleAvgAudioEnergy;
    if ((sampleAvgAudioEnergy > mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[2])
            && (mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[2] > 0)) {
        fireBeatDetectedHighEvent(sampleAvgAudioEnergy);
    }

    mNumberOfSamplesInOneSec++;
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - mSystemTimeStartSec) > 1000) {
        mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[0] = mRunningSoundAvg[0]
                / mNumberOfSamplesInOneSec;
        mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[1] = mRunningSoundAvg[1]
                / mNumberOfSamplesInOneSec;
        mCurrentAvgEnergyOneSec[2] = mRunningSoundAvg[2]
                / mNumberOfSamplesInOneSec;
        mNumberOfSamplesInOneSec = 0;
        mRunningSoundAvg[0] = 0.0;
        mRunningSoundAvg[1] = 0.0;
        mRunningSoundAvg[2] = 0.0;
        mSystemTimeStartSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

// USE INTERFACES IN NEXT UPDATE:
private void fireBeatDetectedLowEvent(double power) {
    // Utility.log("LOW BEAT DETECTED!");
    Game.lowBeat(power);
    if (onBeatDetectedListener != null) {
        onBeatDetectedListener.onBeatDetectedLow();
    }
}

private void fireBeatDetectedMidEvent(double power) {
    // Utility.log("MEDIUM BEAT DETECTED!");
    Game.mediumBeat(power);
    if (onBeatDetectedListener != null) {
        onBeatDetectedListener.onBeatDetectedMid();
    }
}

private void fireBeatDetectedHighEvent(double power) {
    // Utility.log("HIGH BEAT DETECTED!");
    Game.highBeat(power);
    if (onBeatDetectedListener != null) {
        onBeatDetectedListener.onBeatDetectedHigh();
    }
}

public void setOnBeatDetectedListener(OnBeatDetectedListener listener) {
    onBeatDetectedListener = listener;
}

public interface OnBeatDetectedListener {
    public abstract void onBeatDetectedLow();

    public abstract void onBeatDetectedMid();

    public abstract void onBeatDetectedHigh();
}
}
```

It takes a MediaPlayer Object as a parameter and then Calculates Three Different Frequencies Based on the EnergySum of the Byte Data. It is possible to Split the frequencies as many times as you like. I was considering Creating an Array of Frequencies, that each Have a Listener. I then used the Following to Draw a Rectangle:

```
public static void highBeat(double power) {
    HIGH_FREQUENCY += (power * 1000); // ORIGINAL: * 1000
    if (HIGH_FREQUENCY > GameValues.FREQ_MAX) {
        HIGH_FREQUENCY = GameValues.FREQ_MAX;
    }
    updateHighFreq();
}

public static void updateHighFreq() {
    prcnt = HIGH_FREQUENCY * 100 / GameValues.FREQ_MAX;
    if (prcnt < 0)
        prcnt = 0;
    HIGH_F_HEIGHT = (int) (GameValues.FREQ_MAX_HEIGHT * (prcnt / 100));
}
```

This calculates the Height of the Rectangle by Calculating a percentage based on the Max Power and Maximum Height of a Bar. It is not very accurate, but it is the best thing I could come up with. Again, this can be done for as many frequencies as you like. Here are some Links that Helped me out:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/VisualizerTest.java

https://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/518916b8da0af8330dfa9398/android.media.audiofx.Visualizer?tag=out_2013_05_05_07_19_34

Hope I can help anyone else with these issues.